Chrome Developer Tools (F12) Stealing Focus
I'm working with a bar code scanner that is used to scan data & populate a web page.  For this to work I a specific element on the web page to have focus.  This  is working, unless the F12 tools are open & then the Developer Tools have focus.
Is there a way to stop this?  FYI, I tried undocking the F12 tools but the same thing happened, which is the scanner output goes to the F12 tools not the web page.

Pres Ctrl-Shift-P in devtools and type efoc (shows "Emulate a focused page"), then press Enter.
